# DataTables has not rendering image

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables

i'm trying show image  in datatable, but i have a troubles with rendering image, how i may fixed it?
i'm using Django
[image: screen]

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var datatable = $("#asins_list").DataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": links.ajax_get_asins_list,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        'sDom': 'Bfrtip',
        "bSortable": false,
        "bSearch": false,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        responsive: true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
    "targets": 0,
    "data": "remark",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      // return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
      return '<a href="test.png"><img src="test.png"  ' +
          '><b>Competed</b></a>';
    }
  }],
    });
```

Comment: Could you show the resulting html for that cell? Any consile-messages?

Comment: oops, typo in wprd „console“

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate which version you are using, so I assume its the latest (1.10.18). 
In that case please note that `aoColumnDefs` no longer exists, it is now just [`ColumnDefs`](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source).